# Unsupported format character '@' (0x40) at index 81

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-formatting, pexpect

I have taken the pexpect example shown here https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/blob/master/examples/ssh_tunnel.py

However when I try to run it using python 2.7 I get an error saying

```
Unsupported format character '@' (0x40) at index 81
```

If I take the @ out it seems to resolve the error but I get another exception.  I was wondering if it's because in the example the @ is right next to the % which causes wrong interpretation?  if so how do I go about resolving this?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the code is just broken. It should read `%(user)s@%(host)s`.